# PHP session cookie seems to gone when URL does not have WWW in front of it

Tags: php, session, cookies

I put this on my index file:

```
session_set_cookie_params(31536000);
session_start();
```

It keeps users logged in even when the browser is closed and re-opened.

However, it only works when a WWW in front of my URL.  Is there a way to make it work without the WWW in front of the URL?

Comment: There are some similar issues in php.net, check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php#96404 or/and others there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As per the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), use this:

`session_set_cookie_params( 31536000, '/', '.example.com' )`;

This will allow the session cookie to be valid for every path (second argument) and every subdomain of `example.com` (third argument). Replace `.example.com` with your own of course.

Comment: @John, apart from Melsi's comment, of which I was unaware; are you sure both are being served by the same virtual host / directory / script? You wouldn't happen to serve `www` from another script, by any chance, would you?
To be sure, I tested it myself, and for what it's worth: it's working as expected here.

Comment: Somehow it works now.  It seemed to start working after I had logged into the site with the WWW not shown on the URL.